# Columns values concatenation in Oracle

Tags: oracle, group-concat

Please help me to do the following in Oracle.

I have something like column called `id` , and I need in concatenation

```
Id
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
9
```

I need a query which returns `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9`

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you thought about sharing your existing query, rather just asking people to write it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
WITH t(ID) AS
(
SELECT 1 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2 FROM dual
UNION 
SELECT 3 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 4 FROM dual
)
SELECT LISTAGG(ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select ltrim(max(sys_connect_by_path(id, ',')), ',')
  from (select id, rownum t
          from yourtable t)
connect by prior t = t - 1
 start with t = 1;
```